# KLCPopup errors on button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

With **[KLCPopup library](https://github.com/jmascia/KLCPopup)** I have always one of these errors (randomly) when i press one of the button of my view contained in the KLCPopup container:

1. `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSISLinearExpression sendPlus:]`
2. (most of times) `bad_access_exc code=1`

**Here's my code to call the KLCPopup in « FindViewController »**

```
AddFeelingViewController *adf = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddFeelingView"];
adf.userTo = [_userFetch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
adf.controller = self;
adf.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 250.0);

KLCPopup *popup = [KLCPopup popupWithContentView:[adf view] showType:KLCPopupShowTypeBounceIn dismissType:KLCPopupDismissTypeBounceOut maskType:KLCPopupMaskTypeDimmed dismissOnBackgroundTouch:YES dismissOnContentTouch:NO];

[popup show];
```

**And here the code in my « AddFeelingViewController »  :**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {

      super viewDidLoad];
      score = 0;

    if([_controller isKindOfClass:[FindViewController class]]){            
       _controller = (FindViewController*)_controller;     
    }else{
       _controller = (HomeViewController*)_controller;

    }

    - (IBAction)sendPlus:(id)sender { 
       score = 1;
    }
    - (IBAction)sendMinus:(id)sender {     
        score = -1;
    }
    - (IBAction)sendFeeling:(id)sender {

        if([_controller isKindOfClass:[FindViewController class]]){
             if(score !=0 ){
               [_controller addNewFriendship:_userTo andScore:score];
             }

        }else{
             //TODO
        }
     }
```

Everything is well linked in the storyboard and it only crashes if the buttons are linked.

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Hey Smiless, could you let me know if my answer solved your issue? I know it's a bit old, but I'm quite sure that it do the trick :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running to the exact same error as your n°2.
This happens because your `AddFeelingViewController` is released automatically once your code inside `FindViewController` is executed.

Your `AddFeelingViewController` is declared in the current scope only (in the body of a method), so ARC released it once the method has finished its execution.

To solve that, just declare your `AddFeelingViewController` as class variable of `FindViewController`.

In `FindViewController.m` :

```
AddFeelingViewController *myAdfController;

@implementation FindViewController

-(void)displayMyAdf{
    myAdfController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddFeelingView"];
    myAdfController.userTo = [_userFetch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myAdfController.controller = self;
    myAdfController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 250.0);

    KLCPopup *popup = [KLCPopup popupWithContentView:[myAdfController view] showType:KLCPopupShowTypeBounceIn dismissType:KLCPopupDismissTypeBounceOut maskType:KLCPopupMaskTypeDimmed dismissOnBackgroundTouch:YES dismissOnContentTouch:NO];

    [popup show];
}
```